# Access identifier content when using a custom type in Bison

Tags: c, bison, yacc, lex

I have scanner and parser ready, using flex and bison.

The parser is building a tree directly in the actions, and to do so I created a struct called STreeNode and I am using

```
#define YYSTYPE_IS_DECLARED
typedef STreeNode* YYSTYPE;
```

The struct is:

```
typedef struct tagSTreeNode
{
    EOperationType type;
    int count;
    struct tagSTreeNode **children;
    char *string;
} STreeNode;
```

There are like 40 tokens, and for every rule I have something like

```
unlabeled_statement:
        assignment                                                          {$$ = createNode(eUNLABELED_STATEMENT, 1, $1);}
        | function_call_statement                                           {$$ = createNode(eUNLABELED_STATEMENT, 1, $1);}
        | goto                                                              {$$ = createNode(eUNLABELED_STATEMENT, 1, $1);}
        | return                                                            {$$ = createNode(eUNLABELED_STATEMENT, 1, $1);}
        | conditional                                                       {$$ = createNode(eUNLABELED_STATEMENT, 1, $1);}
        | repetitive                                                        {$$ = createNode(eUNLABELED_STATEMENT, 1, $1);}
        | empty_statement                                                   {$$ = createNode(eUNLABELED_STATEMENT, 1, $1);}
        ;
```

The signature for the createNode function is

```
STreeNode *createNode(EOperationType type, int count, ...) {
```

The tree is working fine. The problem is accessing the real value for variable names, function names, etc. Since YYSTYPE is a struct, $x does not have the string value I want to save on the char * string element in the struct.

I have a %token called IDENTIFIER and another called INTEGER, and those should receive the values I want.

Researching, I discovered that I could try and use a union { } to have every token of a specific type. Maybe that could help? And if so, I would necessarily need to specify the type every single token? How can that be implemented?

What about yytext? Couldn't that be used to achieve this goal?

Thank you!

--- **EDIT** --

So I've created

```
%union {
    char *string;
    STreeNode *node;
}
```

and specified every terminal and non terminal type to be one of those. The nodes are still working, but the strings using ($1 for example) are returning null.

Do I need to change anything in the scanner as well? My scanner has:

```
[a-zA-Z][a-z0-9A-Z]*        { return IDENTIFIER; }
[0-9]+                      { return INTEGER; }
```

Thanks again.

Comment: If you are using bison, why is this tagged `yacc`?

Comment: Just a small question, unrelated to your problem, but why do you create nodes for things that doesn't need it? Like instead of creating a new node for `conditioal` why not just simply set `$$` to `$1`? That will simplify your tree a little, and lead to way fewer nodes in it.

Comment: @ScottHunter The `flex` tag is for [Apache Flex](http://flex.apache.org/) not the GNU lex clone, so I removed it.

Comment: As for your problem, you probably should read about [the `%union` directive](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Union-Decl.html#Union-Decl) and [token type names](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Token-Decl.html). There are *many* example on how to use these if you just search a little.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You are correct, but since this is for educational purposes, one of the things the teacher can check is how many nodes for a particular element, for example. BTW thank you for editing it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude by using the %union directive, I would need to specify the type for each one, correct?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. But if you want to use different types for some for terminals and non-terminals then you unfortunately have no other way. Unless you want the *lexer* to create the leaf nodes, and initialize the `string` member (which I assume the text from the lexer would be in)?

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it! I'll also follow your suggestion and see if I can clean up the tree / the parser a bit.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've made the changes, but its still not working. I've edited the question, can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your tokens have a type set for them, the lexer needs to set `yylval` to the type in question.  Something like:

```
[a-zA-Z][a-z0-9A-Z]*        { yylval.string = strdup(yytext); return IDENTIFIER; }
[0-9]+                      { yylval.string = strdup(yytext); return INTEGER; }
```